# How do I change the numbering of sections in articles to be numbered with a .0?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I tried searching for about an hour so I'm confident otherwise.

I would like sections to be numbered X.0, for example 1.0 Introduction instead of 1 Introduction. I agree with the default but my university does not apparently.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please, always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your questions. In the case of this question it would show us the class you are using. So it would help us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not say what documentclass you are using, which is probably relevant. I'll just `book` and hope for the best (this is one of the reasons why it is good to provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)).

The naive thing to do is to redefine `\thesection` so as to add a `0`:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
```

This isn't what you want, however, as now the subsections will come out as `1.0.1` etc. So you need to define `\thesubsection` as well.  The following seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\begin{document}

  \chapter{First chapter}
  \section{First section}
  \subsection{First subsection}
  \section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

This said, a simpler solution, which may also look better because it will look more consistent, is simply to use `\subsection` instead of `\section` throughout.

Comment: Apologies I'm using article, but it works. Thank you so much! Exactly what I wanted. The only problem is the numbering touches the section name when using 10 or more sections.

Comment: I did a hack fix of \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em} I know it's bad but the report needs to be done

Answer (score 1):

You just want that `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` do the same thing.

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\section{Second section}

\end{document}
```